# How do you escape a . (full stop) or / so it doesn't change URL's meaning?

Tags: angularjs, url, asp.net-web-api, escaping, angular-resource

I have a Web API 2.0 service which defines a particular route:

```
/api/someEntityGroup/{entityName}
```

I'm calling this enpoint using Angular `$resource` service.

The problem is when user wants to provide an entity name with characters that have a specific meaning in URL:

- 404 Not found - `.` (full stop), `/`, `+`
- 400 Bad request - `?`, `:`, `&`, `%`, `*`, `<`, `>`

And these are the ones I've encountered. There may be others that may be problematic as well and I'm not even aware of them (yet).

If I use `window.escape()` function these still don't work, but I mainly get 404 back (the only exception being `*` which still returns 400 Bad request).

### My code

Angular resource creation:

```
.factory("entityResource", ["$resource", function() {
    return $resource("/api/entities/:id", null, {
        search: {
            method: "GET",
            url: "/api/entities/:name",
            isArray: true
        }
    });
}]);
```

How I call it in my code:

```
entityResource.search({ query: scope.name }, function(data) {
    ...
});
```

My Api controller action:

```
[RoutePrefix("/api/entities")]
public class EntitiesController: ApiController
{
    [Route("{searchQuery}")]
    public IEnumerable<Interest> Get(string searchQuery)
    {
        return this.interestService.Search(searchQuery);
    }

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can shed some light on your 404 Not found issue when using `.`, `/`, `+` characters.

The issue isn't with Angular but rather with Web API and the way it resolves routes. Urls that Web API interprets as being managed resources (e.g. static content, pages etc.) it will try to resolve independently.

Set the following in your web.config to disable this behavior and force WebAPI to run all requests through your modules:

```
<system.webServer>
   <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
</system.webServer>
```

*Just a warning -* If your Web API is hosted together with something like MVC or a static website, the above is not recommended as it will force all managed resources (pages, MVC routes, content[css,js,images]) through your API modules and there will be a performance impact. However, if all the API is doing is serving resource routes I would recommend enabling the above.